# Iterate over the node pair set in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I stored a relatively huge graph in neo4j.
What I'm trying to do is to calculate path count by relationship types.

> MATCH path = (n1)-[e1]->()-[e2]->(n3)
>
> WHERE n1.id = '1' AND n3.id = '3'
>
> RETURN type(e1),type(e2),count(path)

I already have pre-selected set of ids for n1 & n3 nodes as below.
(n1,n3) = (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (4,5), (4,6) ........

What is the best way to execute the above queries for the id pairs in neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a literal list of list pairs, and UNWIND the lists into rows. Ideally you'd pass it to your query as a parameter, but here's an example using the literal list:

```
UNWIND [['1','3'], ['2','3'], ['2','4'], ['4','5']] as pair
MATCH path = (n1)-[e1]->()-[e2]->(n3)
WHERE n1.id = pair[0] AND n3.id = pair[1]
RETURN type(e1),type(e2),count(path)
```

Comment: Hi @InverseFalcon . Thank you for your reply. What if there are more than 4 pairs to unwind? 10,000 pairs for example.

Comment: No difference. The UNWIND will ensure a row for each pair (so 10k rows if unwinding a 10k element list), then the subsequent Cypher will execute per row. That said, it would be best if your MATCH is supported with labels in the pattern, and indexes associated with the label and property you're using for lookup.